# Как распарсить большой xml-файл с помощью Python?

Tags: python, xml, beautiful-soup

Столкнулся с необходимостью распарсить большой xml файл (более 700к строк) используя Python. Необходимо найти и выписать кадастровые номера с категорией "земли населенных пунктов". В данном файле их должно быть 67 шт.

Желаемый вывод: кадастровый номер - категория

[Ссылка](https://disk.yandex.ru/d/RDevGkUBYbj74w) на xml-файл.

Comment: Стандартные библиотеки уже пробовали? https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.html

Comment: И что у вас не получается?  

Comment: @Amgarak написать скрипт :D, нашел подобный вопрос на форуме, но не совсем понимаю как переписать код для моего случая. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1475587

Comment: В стандартной библиотеке (или в `lxml`) для больших файлов используется парсеры `SAX`, которые не начинают с того, что грузят весь файл в  память в виде структуры. Впрочем, при современной объемах  памяти, может и  700к строк за разумный срок загрузится... если строки не слишком большие :)

Comment: Посмотрел файл... никакой он не большой :) грузится мгновенно. Пример с BeautifulSoup не смотрите - это излишнее тут. Пройдите прямо по документации - https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#module-xml.etree.ElementTree

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот, специально для вас. Не знаю насколько верно уловил ваше желание, но по аналогии можете доработать:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

# Загрузка XML-документа
tree = ET.parse('report-043a81fb-ae32-4025-85ad-6a3778249c8c-number-52-01[0].xml')
root = tree.getroot()

# Функция для обработки блока данных
def process_land_record(land_record):
    data = {}

    # Обработка данных внутри блока
    common_data = land_record.find('.//common_data')
    if common_data is not None:
        cad_number = common_data.findtext('.//cad_number')
        data['cad_number'] = cad_number

    subtype = land_record.find('.//subtype')
    if subtype is not None:
        subtype_code = subtype.findtext('.//code')
        subtype_value = subtype.findtext('.//value')
        data['subtype_code'] = subtype_code
        data['subtype_value'] = subtype_value

    # Добавьте обработку других данных, если необходимо

    return data

# Обработка всех блоков данных в документе
all_land_records = root.findall('.//land_record')
for index, land_record in enumerate(all_land_records, start=1):
    data_for_block = process_land_record(land_record)
    print(f"Данные для блока {index}:", data_for_block)
    print()
```

Пример ответа:

```
Данные для блока 64: {'cad_number': '52:18:0040150:69', 'subtype_code': '01', 'subtype_value': 'Землепользование'}

Данные для блока 65: {'cad_number': '52:18:0040150:70', 'subtype_code': '01', 'subtype_value': 'Землепользование'}

Данные для блока 66: {'cad_number': '52:18:0040150:71', 'subtype_code': '01', 'subtype_value': 'Землепользование'}

Данные для блока 67: {'cad_number': '52:18:0040150:75', 'subtype_code': '01', 'subtype_value': 'Землепользование'}
```